# Mysql-запросы внутри ob_start

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.  
Есть код:

```
$parser = new Parser();  
$terms = array('line', 'round');  
$parser->set_terms( $terms );  
ob_start(array($parser,'replace_in_page'));
```

В начале срипта инициализируется парсер, через функцию `ob_start`, устанавливается callback-функция, и все, что внутри буффера вывода (переменная `$terms`, любое из слов), заменяется на `<strong>{{term}}</strong>`, то есть парсер ищет их и вставляет в `strong`.  
Нужно чтобы в функции `replace_in_page` при нахождении любого из терминов найденные термины добавлялись в базу данных, но они не добавляются.

Сделал по-другому:

```
$parser = new Parser();  
$terms = array('line', 'round');  
$parser->set_terms( $terms );  
echo $parser->replace_in_page( file_get_content('http://site.ru') );
```

И все работает как должно, вывод не работает в пределах обработки буфера, как это можно поправить?